# Track calls to web services without debugger, .NET

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to find out all calls to WCF web services without using a debugger. At the moment, I am  using WCF tracing and .NET tracing.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: You could use a logging framework like log4net or NLog, but they have to be added manually to your services...your best bet is the built in WCF tracing.  Are you having some sort of issue with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some set of custom data you need to track, I recommend implementing a custom `IOperationInvoker`.  From there, you can fairly easily write key data to a log file; what method was called, how long it took to execute, the passed in parameters, etc...

Answer (score -1):

If your web service is backed by a database you could handle the tracking in a trigger/stored proc (this is how we do it at work), alternatively you could review the IIS logs (if hosting through IIS).

Comment: Just curious, can you host WCF services inside of anything but IIS?

Comment: @SoWeLie - Yes. WCF services can be hosted by just about any type of .NET application (Winforms and Console even). I've never tried it in a setup app, nor would I recommend it.

Comment: Oh right, good call.  I forgot about the service host business.  I was  thinking you knew of some other open source type application server to host .NET applications, which I'd never heard of.

Comment: @SoWeLie - Well [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development) does support a large subset of WCF as well. Their todo list includes a few significant components though.